# Proving that the angle subtended at vertex of a regular tetrahedron is less than 60

Tags: geometry

I have two points P and Q which lie in the interior of a regular tetrahedron ABCD. I need to prove that the angle PAQ, ie the angle subtended by a line segment lying entirely in the interior of a regular tetrahedron ABCD  is always less than 60.

My only progress in the question was that if I produce AP and AQ to intersect the plane BCD at two points E and F, then I need to prove that angle EAF is less than 60. I did this because I find working with two points in a plane easier than working with two random points in space.

Comment: 1) Is P one of the vertices? 2) If so do you mean angle APB? (i.e. with P as the point where the angle's vertex is, so PA and PB are the sides of the angle?

Comment: I think you mean "I have two points $P$ and $Q$ that lie in the interior of a regular tetrahedron $ABCD$".

Comment: You have not said what $P$ and $Q$ are, OP; also, $A$ and $B,$ being vertices of the tetrahedron, cannot simultaneously be in its interior.

Comment: I'll call the interior points $P_1$ and $P_2$. A somewhat mechanical way to proceed is to express the interior points using [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) in terms of $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. That is, $$P_i = \frac{a_i A + b_i B + c_i C + d_i D }{a_i+b_i+c_i+d_i}$$ (If the $a_i$, etc, are all strictly positive, then $P_i$ is strictly interior to $ABCD$.) Then compute $$\cos\angle P_1AP_2 = \frac{\overrightarrow{AP_1}\cdot\overrightarrow{AP_2}}{|\overrightarrow{AP_1}||\overrightarrow{AP_2}|}$$ and compare this to $1/2$. Messy, but doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the question is to prove that any line segment contained in the regular tetrahedron cannot subtend up to an angle of $60°$ at a vertex, then one way of doing that is to:

(1) Observe that any such line segment that is not parallel to the face opposite the vertex in question automatically subtends an angle smaller than a segment of equal length which is parallel to the face,

(2) Note that the largest segment not outside the tetrahedron that is parallel to the opposite face must lie in that face,

(3) See that since this face is an equilateral triangle, the largest segment not outside the triangle but lying in its plane is a side of the triangle,

(4) Finally see that this side subtends an angle $60°$ at the said vertex; that therefore, since this is the limit of all possible line segments satisfying all our conditions, no other such segments can pass the bound set by the limit.

Hopefully, you can make this rigorous.